# Get specific coordinates from a Matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix

I have a 9x9 matrix, but for this post I made it smaller to not paste a larger matrix. What I need to do is that I need to get the edges, diagonals, and points not being used based on a specific coordinate.
The user of the program will give a coordinate of x and y.
Below is a legend of how the matrix must be labeled.

Legend

- X = **Users Coordinates**
- E = **Edges**
- D = **Diagonals**
- . = **Not being used**

```
.   |   D   |   E   |   D   |   .   
.   |   E   |   X   |   E   |   .   
.   |   D   |   E   |   D   |   .
```

I have gotten to the part where you can give the coordinate inputs.
But when I try to calculate the edges I get repeating numbers.
I also need to add logic for the corners. In the event the users places a coordinate in the corner of the matrix, so I don't get a IndexOutOfBounds error.

```java
        String[][] board = new String[9][9];
        Integer x = Integer.parseInt(clean[0]);
        Integer y = Integer.parseInt(clean[1]);

        board[x][y] = "X";
        List<Integer[]> results = new ArrayList<>();

        // Coordinates (1,5)
        results.add(new Integer[]{x--,y});
        results.add(new Integer[]{x++,y});
        results.add(new Integer[]{x,y++});
        results.add(new Integer[]{x,y--});
```

For getting the diagonals, I was thinking of using the the left and right edge and increase their count by one and minus one.

```java
Integer topLeftDiagonal = new Integer[]{x--,y++}; 
Integer bottomLeftDiagonal = new Integer[]{x--,y--};
Integer topRightDiagonal = new Integer[]{x++,y++}; 
Integer bottomRightDiagonal = new Integer[]{x++,y--};
```

#### My output is wrong.

Original coordinate:    1,5    (**Correct**)

Getting Edges:

X:  1   Y:  5      (**Wrong**)

X:  0   Y:  5      (**Correct**)

X:  1   Y:  5      (**Wrong**)

X:  1   Y:  6      (**Correct**)

#### The ouput would be right if

Getting Edges:

X:  **2**   Y:  5      (**Right**)

X:  0   Y:  5      (**Correct**)

X:  1   Y:  **4**     (**Wrong**)

X:  1   Y:  6      (**Correct**)

Comment: I suggest to *not* mix lists and arrays.

Comment: Furthermore, you are using the increment operator, that'll update the values of `x` and `y` too. Use `x + 1` and `x - 1` etc instead.

Comment: At last, I suggest you create a `Coordinate` class instead of using an `Integer[]`. That's more OOP-like. You can then define methods to retrieve edges and diagonals, e.g. `getNorthernEdge()` or something.